# How to authenticate instagram and like and comment on a pic?

Tags: android, authentication, instagram

I am making an instagram app in which i will show all the pics of a user ( by entering the name of the user ), so the user without authenticating can see the timeline of that user.

But i want the user to be able to like and comment the pic, for that authentication is required, in facebook they provide sdk but in instagram i could'nt find any sdk and third party lib.

Can anyone help me in authentication, liking and commenting in instaGram??

Comment: Take a look at http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

you can download the SDK from https://github.com/markchang/android-instagram.

Answer (score 0):

Check
 [instagram integration](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth)

[instagram for uploading pics](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/01/android-instagram-integration.html)

surely help you.....